# How to create a Ruby timer that pauses while its thread is sleeping?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, timer, benchmarking, stopwatch

My Ruby application processes jobs that each take ~10 seconds to execute.  Each job spends a lot of time waiting for IO.  I have timers that use simple Time.now comparisons to record how long each stage of the job takes:

```
def timer
  t = Time.now
  yield
  (Time.now - t).seconds
end

timer do
  # IO
end
=> 1.342
```

Originally, I processed all jobs sequentially, and this was great except that the machine was idle 50% of the time (due to IO).

I shifted to a multithreaded model to recoup some IO time.  Now I spawn a new thread for each job, up to a maximum of 10 simultaneous threads.  This works great, except that, when a thread gets preempted while running a timer block, the timer keeps "running" while the thread is sleeping, causing the timer to return an artificially inflated number.

What I need is a way to figure out the actual *run time* of the timer block, ignoring time spent sleeping.  Is there a way to achieve this, such as asking Thread.current how much time it's spent running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) does this by measuring both wall-clock time and CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure anything other than wall-clock time, as you're doing here, you need to use something like the [rusage](https://github.com/sandofsky/rusage) gem that is a wrapper around the UNIX `getrusage` method.

That should give you a break-down of the time spent actually executing, not waiting.

Comment: You'd have to dig into pthreads more to find that out for sure. As far as I know that's only per-process or per-process-group.